# Scrape a website from chrome console with javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, console, wait

I'm trying to scrape a webpage that contains a table of 1000 elements. The webpage updates a tag whenever an element in the table is clicked. From the chrome console, I want to click on each element, wait for the tag to be updated and download the tag. Currently I am doing the following:

```
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
  document.querySelectorAll('element_in table')[i].click()
  text = document.querySelector('tag_to_read_from').innerHTML
  // download text
}
```

The problem is that there is a delay in the tag being updated after an element in the table is clicked. As a result, due to the asynchronous nature of javascript, the script is downloading 1000 empty files.

Is there a way to wait for X seconds after clicking on an element, and then download the updated tag?

Comment: `setTimeout` is a great way to wait for a duration of time to pass.  Since this is something you are doing in the browser console, you don't have to get much more complex than that.  You will, however, have to resturcture how you do your loop though

Comment: You'll want to use [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to wait until "*the tag is being updated*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function scrape (index, max) {
  document.querySelectorAll('element_in table')[index].click();
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    // download text

    if (index < max) scrape(++index, max);
  }, 5000);
}

scrape(0, 1000);
```

You can use a timeout to delay the logic.  Just pick a big enough time.